# Issues with creating a jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to create a jar file of my Java Maven project. I tried searching quite a bit but I can't seem to make it work.

The error i get is "no main manifest attribute in *path to the jar*".

I use this plugin to create the jar and then later build it.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My main class is called simply Main and it is shown in the MANIFEST.MF file as Main-Class: Main which I think should be correct.

I appreciate every piece of advice, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the `<configuration>` tag be before the `<executions>` tag instead of inside it? Atleast that's how I always right it.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh You can nest it to supply configuration options to only a specific execution.

Comment: I copied your code to an old project i had and it worked perfectly. All i changed was the main class. Are you sure your main class isn't in a package?

Comment: @AbhinavSingh I think it should be, I didn't create any specific package for my Main class. My packages look like [this](http://imgur.com/a/3DvPs).

Comment: @HonzaŠtefánik From the looks of things you are using android studio. Why dont you right click on the Main class and select `copy qualified name` and then paste into your maven config. Last i remember android studio doesn't do default packages.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh I am actually using IntelliJ Idea. Thank's for the help, I appreciate. Although I have now successfully solved the issue. I'd close the question but it seems like I can't.

Comment: @HonzaŠtefánik answer the question yourself with how you solved it and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my  configures .maybe is helpful

pom.xml

```
<pluginManagement>  
            <plugins>  
                <plugin>  
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>  
                    <version>1.0.0</version>  
                    <configuration>  
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>  
                            <pluginExecutions>  
                                <pluginExecution>  
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>  
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>  
                                        <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>  
                                        <goals>  
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                            <goal>single</goal>
                                        </goals>  
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>  
                                    <action>  
                                        <ignore />  
                                    </action>  
                                </pluginExecution>  
                            </pluginExecutions>  
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>  
                    </configuration>  
                </plugin>  
            </plugins>  
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>  
                    <execution>  
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>  
                        <goals>  
                            <goal>run</goal>  
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>  
                            <tasks>
                                <copy file="${project.basedir}/script/startup.sh" 
                                    tofile="${project.build.directory}/bin/startup.sh" overwrite="true"/>
                                 <copy file="${project.build.directory}/classes/config.properties" 
                                    tofile="${project.build.directory}/conf/config.properties"/>
                                 <copy file="${project.build.directory}/classes/jdbc.properties" 
                                    tofile="${project.build.directory}/conf/jdbc.properties"/>
                            </tasks>  
                        </configuration>  
                    </execution>  
                </executions>  
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>../lib/</classpathPrefix>

                            <mainClass>com.bootstrap.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/bin</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

A few comments on your configuration:

1) It seems you have an invalid XML for plugins. According to [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html), it should be something like this:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        [...]
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            [...]
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

2) The `mainClass` tag should contain your full qualified main class e.g. `com.your.package.Main`. Unless your `Main` class is not under any package, you might want to change that.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to scope configuration options to a specific execution.

Comment: @chrylis. The answer states "it seems". Also, the second point is still valid. Instead of -1 answers, why don't you provide a useful answer?